# What do you call a lower/upper bound that is the best one?

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, performance

I have developed an upper bound on the number of vertices of a particular graph. This bound is the best possible bound that can be found for any given instance. What do you call such a bound? If it were an optimization problem then I would call it the optimal value or the optimal bound. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you're looking for is [tight bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds#Tight_bounds) or in your case a *tight upper bound*.

Comment: Thanks MGriisser. That definition does not mention whether it is used for one instance of a problem or all instances of it. Not sure but I remember once someone told me if I find an upper bound and be able to find one family of instances of the problem satisfying that upper bound then the upper bound is said to be tight.